# How to return all value of column after calculation laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table that stores the **bets** from users. This **bets** table has relationship with **users** table.

| id | user_id | bet_type | bet_price | bet_round |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 15 | 1 |

I select all from the bets table where bet_type = 1 and bet_round = $x_game_round . When I get them, I can calculate on bet_price column. In my case, I have two users with user_id=1 and user_id=2 who bet on bet_type=1. When I return, I can only see winning price for user_id=1.
What I want is to return win_price for each user that bets with bet_type = 1.

I try in my controller as below.

```
$x_game_round = $x_value["gameRound"];
  

    if($x_value["winner"] === 1) {
        
        $winners = DB::table('bets')
        ->where('bet_type', '=', '1')
        ->where('bet_round', '=', $x_game_round)
        ->get();
       

        if($winners){
            foreach($winners as $winner) {
                $bet_price = $winner->bet_price;
                // echo $winner->user_id;
                $win_price = $this->calculateBasicPayout('1', $bet_price);
                return $win_price;

            }
        }
        
        
    }

public function calculateBasicPayout($bet_type, $bet_price){

        $commission = 5;
        
        if($bet_type === '1')
        {
            // take out 5% of Winning amount.
            $commissionAmount = ($commission / 100) * $bet_price;
            $payoutAmount = ($bet_price * 2) - $commissionAmount;
            return $payoutAmount;

        }elseif($bet_type === '2')
        {
            $payoutAmount = $bet_type * 2;
            return $payoutAmount;

        }elseif($bet_type === '3')
        {
            $payoutAmount = $bet_type * 8;
            return $payoutAmount;
        }
       
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re only ever looping a single `$winner` as in your `foreach` loop you have a `return` statement which breaks out of your execution.

Instead you want to assign `$winning_price` to your `$winner`, or some other variable and remove the return statement.